# Can I get the current users id from a session to in api controller

Tags: laravel

I wants to get user id from home controller to api controller , I am storing user id in session and try to get id in api controller but its always says non-object how to get user id please help me..Below are my code..

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Session;
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
       $userdata = Auth::user();
      // return $userdata;
       Session::put('login_user_id',Auth::user()->id);

       $uid = Session::get('login_user_id');
           dd($uid);
           exit;
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

I want to get user id in BlogController.php

BlogController.php

```
  public function index()
    {
       $userdata = Auth::user();
      // return $userdata;
       Session::put('login_user_id',Auth::user()->id);

       $uid = Session::get('login_user_id');
           dd($uid);
           exit;
        return view('home');
    }
```

In HomeController i am getting user id but o not getting in BlogController.

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;

class User extends \Eloquent implements Authenticatable
{
    use AuthenticableTrait;
    protected $fillable = ['first_name','last_name','username','password','mobile','email','token'];

     public function blog()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Blog');
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you user api routes? If yes then you can't API and Web routes use different middlewares, you will need some sort of API KEY that will be assosiated with USER.

Check RouteProvider and Middlware Kernel

Comment: please code for me..@Froxz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session is not surpported in API. In place of this you can use [Redis](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redis)

Comment: Please try this link. In the documentation it describe the code step by step. If you stuck with any issue then I can help you. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redis

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel API default setup doesn't include session. You can't get the session in API controller. You can pass the user ID as parameter to API controller, however, there will be some security issues and it is not recommended.

Comment: then how to get user id..@Iyathurai Iyngaran

Comment: You can pass the userID to API controller using GET OR POST.